# Is energy required to preserve information on a disk?

Tags: electromagnetism, information

I was just wondering if the large files I have on my PC, which have remained there for years, take up some energy to remain preserved. Just curious. Maybe a silly question after all, but I would like to know how much energy I might have used while preserving many unused files often measuring in GBs.

Comment: Not as far as I know, your data is stored in  magnetic domains on the disc and, as such, should last indefinitely,  unless a strong external magnetic field affects them.

Answer (score 1):

No, it does not need additional energy. The HDDs record data by magnetizing a thin film of ferromagnetic material and do not require power for maintaining data.

Comment: You mean permanent magnetization is involved?

Comment: Imagine trillions of small iron nails, each of which can be orientated in a specific position when a strong magnetic filed is applied to them. The drive plate has a magnetic nature strong enough to keep them in their set position (so yes, this part is permanent), but by applying a much stronger field (from the write heads), the small nails will be moved to a different position. So preservation of their alignment is both safe and permanent.